# Auto-link phone numbers in a pdf file

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

In Adobe Acrobat, you can process a document using the "Create Links from URLs" function to automatically detect email and web links in a pdf file and make them live links.

I want to do the same thing for phone numbers.
You can manually tag phone numbers using the tel: code. (tel:+000000000). and they will be active links when viewed from a smartphone. (click the link to initiate a phone call)

I am looking for a script or third party plug-in that can automatically detect phone numbers and tag them. Has anyone run across anything that might do this?

This is probably not a design question, but someone here must have run into this before.

Comment: wouldn't the link format depend on the phone being used? what I mean is, the protocol for triggering a call on an iphone is probably not the same as on Android

Comment: maybe. I have not tested on Android. - But that's not the question. How would one tag many phone numbers in a pdf file, without having to do them all manually?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, you can probably script it to automate this even more but this should get you started in a fairly efficient way of doing it.

First, find your phone numbers and replace them with one of the Android+iOS accepted formats. According to Tutsplus:

> 555-5555 (iPhone Only)
>   (555) 555-5555 (Android + iPhone)
>       +1 (555) 555-5555 (iPhone Only)
>       555 5555 (iPhone Only)
>       555 555 5555 (Android + iPhone)
>       +1 555 555 5555 (iPhone Only)
>       555.5555 (iPhone Only)
>       555.555.5555 (Android + iPhone)
>       +1 555.555.5555 (iPhone Only)

So let's use the decimal point style, 555.555.5555. Do a find and replace using **GREP**.

Find what: `\(?(\d\d\d)\)?[-. ‑]?(\d\d\d)[-. ‑]?(\d\d\d\d)`
Change to: `tel:$1.$2.$3`

Now your phone numbers should be `tel:123.456.7890`

Now do another find searching for `tel:^9^9^9.^9^9^9.^9^9^9^9`. Click find, then click `New Hyperlink from URL`. Then find next and repeat.

Once done doing `New Hyperlink from URL` do another find and replace to remove the `tel:` from the phone numbers. If you want you can even change the format again.

That find next and repeat is something you could probably script but that's up to you.

Comment: I think I would have to script this, correct? - I see no other way to use GREP within Acrobat except through a Javascript. - Thanks

Comment: @Rsiel ooh my mistake I answered entirely for InDesign. Not sure how to do in Acrobat and won't be able to check now until Monday. If I remember I'll look then though and see if I can figure anything out. Use to work for phone book company.

Comment: Wait… there’s _no way at all_ to make Android understand international phone numbers? That beggars belief.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ... I said nothing at all about international phone numbers so have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: The only three formats that include international dialling codes are listed as “iPhone only”; I assumed that if Android is unable to parse _+1 555 555 5555_ for a US/Canadian number, it would also be unable to parse, say, _+33 33 33 33 33_ for a French number. It seems quite bizarre that this should be so, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/click-to-call/?hl=en#use-the-international-dialing-format

Comment: Ah, good—so it’s Tutsplus’ “iPhone only” notes that are either incorrect or outdated. Good to get that confirmed.

Answer (score -5):

This one should work... tel:XXX-XXX-XXXX

Comment: Should? Why? Have you proofed it? You saw the accepted answer?